# AjaxConvert throws parse error on Jsonp callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I am making Ajax call with Jsonp DataType. And the JsonpCallback Function gets executed, while processing JsonpCallBack method, it throws error as '

> parse error , MyScript.JsonpSuccessCallBack was not called'

While Debugging , i got that the error is hitted from AjaxCovert function(return statement) in jquery Library file.

```
var MyScript = {};
    $.ajax({      
            url: 'https:' + domain + 'captcha/captcha-generate-token',
            type: 'GET',    
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            async: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: 'MyScript.JsonpSuccessCallBack',
            error:MyScript.error,
});

MyScript.JsonpSuccessCallBack = function(response){
    //stuffs
}
MyScript.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

I am getting a valid API response with `MyScript.JsonpSuccessCallBack({"STATUS":"success","CONTENT_TYPE":"application\/json","CK":"wTnoiHvP-eLyCWO0xG-KIrJ3AXnLm7awLH-xETjLPNLd4Kkt"})`

The error thrown is as below

```
Error: MyScript.JsonpSuccessCallBack was not called
at Function.jQuery.extend.error (http://www.someWebsite.com/web/scripts/jquery/jquery.js:248:9)
at jQuery.ajaxPrefilter.s.converters.script json (http://www.someWebsite.com/web/scripts/jquery/jquery.js:9893:12)
at ajaxConvert (http://www.someWebsite.com/web/scripts/jquery/jquery.js:8843:19)
at done (http://www.someWebsite.com/web/scripts/jquery/jquery.js:9260:15)
at HTMLScriptElement.jQuery.ajaxTransport.s.send.script.onload.script.onreadystatechange (www.someWebsite.com/web/scripts/jquery/jquery.js:9831:8)
```

The control reaches the JsonpSuccessCallBack method and through ajaxconvert() meth in lib file, then throws an error. I Cant get why this error is thrown.

I have googled a lot for this issue and followed the steps mentioned but cant fix this,Can anyOne please help me to Fix this issue..

Thank You in advance :-)

Comment: If you've found a solution, please share.